# If $m>1$ is odd and $\mathrm{ord}_ma = 2t$, then show that $a^t\equiv -1\pmod m$.

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

> If $m>1$ is odd and $\mathrm{ord}_ma = 2t$, then $a^t\equiv -1\pmod m$.

I am struggling with this problem. I could use the property of ord to get $a^{2t} \equiv 1\pmod m$, which is $a^t\equiv -1\pmod m$ or $a^t\equiv 1\pmod m$. I was trying to prove $a^t\equiv 1\pmod m$ is not true by using $\mathrm{ord}_ma\mid\phi(m)$. It implies $2t\mid m-1$. But do not know what to do next, can someone help me with this?

Comment: If we had $a^t \equiv 1 \mod(m)$, what would that say about the order of $a$?

Comment: Then $ord_ma = t$ which is a contradiction, right? Because 2t is the min exponent.

Comment: You got it! :) ${}$

Comment: Thanks! But what if $2|m$, then $ord_ma=t$ hold right? Because m is even.

Comment: No, what I mean if m is even, then $a^t \equiv -1\pmod m$ does not hold, right?

Comment: Actually it does - for example, if you take the group of integers modulo $5$, then $2^4 = 1$ and $2^2 = -1$. The proof shows why this must be the case in general - because (like $4$, with respect to $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5$) the order, $2t$, is the smallest power we can raise $a$ to and obtain $1$.

Comment: Alright, thanks for helping.

Comment: Wait, I'm sorry, I see the subtlety you're asking about. For example you could have the multiplicative group of $8$ and fail to have the property hold for, say, $3$. I was thinking of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ in my head.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is **not** true when $m$ is composite. For example, for $m=91=13 \cdot 7$ then $\text{ord}_{91}(3)=6$ but $3^3 \not\equiv -1 \pmod{91}$.

It is true when $m$ is a prime. The proof is not hard. Just like you wrote above, $m \mid (a^t-1)(a^t+1)$ so either $m \mid a^t-1$ or $m \mid a^t+1$ since $m$ is prime. But if $m \mid a^t-1$ then $\text{ord}_m(a) \mid t$ or $\text{ord}_m(a) \le t<2t$, a contradiction. Thus $m \mid a^t+1$.